# Is it possible to have non-trivial kernel and independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

We have the following transformation from $P_2$ to $P_2$:

> $T(ax^2 + bx + c)$
> $=(a+b)x^2 + (c+d)x + a$

The kernel in this case is not trivial which means the null space is not trivial hence the vectors `

> $x^2$, $x$, $1$

are not linearly independent(wrong?) but they are in reality linearly independent.

Can someone tell me where am i wrong with my thought process?
thank you

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by the first equation, as you have not defined a function, you've just written down an expression. But I suspect you are confusing the vectors with their images. If $T\colon V\to V$ is a linear transformation with non-trivial kernel, and you take a basis for $V$, then the image of those vectors will not be linearly independent, even though the original vectors of course are.

Comment: yes exactly i am confusing them, can you please elaborate on what you said? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: What is there to elaborate? Just don't confuse them. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: The (false) conclusion you gave, the $1,x,x^2$ are linearly dependent, has nothing to do with the map $T$. Think about why you thought that a statement about $T$ could lead to your conclusion (which is something only you can know), and you will find where your reasoning went wrong.